# Issue with Spring Roo's Data on Demand and maven-run integration tests

Tags: maven, integration-testing, aop, aspectj, spring-roo

I use Spring Roo and **I rely on Roo's data on demand for my integration tests**.

I recently realized that the very same integration tests that **run smoothly in Eclipse break when I run them from Maven**.

The problem seems to come from Spring Roo's data on demand. For instance I get errors such as...

> testFindPlisByMultiFieldWithNothingSet(trc.suivi.core.repository.PliRepositoryTest):
>   expected:<10> but was:<0>

...for the following test...

```
@Test
public void testFindPlisByMultiFieldWithNothingSet() {
    PliDataOnDemand dod = new PliDataOnDemand();
    dod.init();
    PliQueryInfo pliQueryInfo = new PliQueryInfo();
    List<Pli> plis = pliRepository.findPlisByMultiField(pliQueryInfo, null, null, null, null);
    assertEquals(10, plis.size());
}
```

...indicating that **`dod.init()` does not populate my in-memory database**...

FYI, PliDataOnDemand is a data on demand class for one of our entities called Pli.

Can anyone please help?

EDIT:

From the command line: **I ran "mvn test"**

From eclipse: **I just ran the test from the eclipse menu**

Maven version: **3.0.4**

EDIT 2:

Output from aspectJ maven plugin:

```
[INFO] 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java:8) is annotated with @Component type annotation from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:26)
[INFO] 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java:8) is annotated with @Configurable type annotation from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_Configurable.aj:11)
[INFO] Extending interface set for type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) to include 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.ConfigurableObject' (AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect.aj)
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped field from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'java.util.Random trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.rnd')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped field from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'java.util.List<trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli> trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.data')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped field from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'trc.suivi.core.domain.UtilisateurDataOnDemand trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.utilisateurDataOnDemand')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.getNewTransientPli(int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setDateAnnulation(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setDateCreation(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setDateModification(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setDateReception(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setFDV(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setIdentifiant(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setNbPlisFDVEstime(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setNumeroPli(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setPaiement(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setStatut(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.setTypePli(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli, int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.getSpecificPli(int)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.getRandomPli()')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'boolean trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.modifyPli(trc.suivi.core.domain.Pli)')
[INFO] Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java) has intertyped method from 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand_Roo_DataOnDemand.aj:'void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.init()')
[INFO] Join point 'initialization(void org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.ConfigurableObject.<init>())' in Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java:8) advised by before advice from 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' (spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.class:78(from AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'initialization(void org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.ConfigurableObject.<init>())' in Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java:8) advised by afterReturning advice from 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' (spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.class:87(from AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
[INFO] Join point 'initialization(void trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand.<init>())' in Type 'trc.suivi.core.domain.PliDataOnDemand' (PliDataOnDemand.java:8) advised by afterReturning advice from 'org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect' (spring-aspects-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar!AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.class:87(from AbstractDependencyInjectionAspect.aj)) [with runtime test]
```

EDIT 3:

I get this:

```
 testFindPlisByMultiFieldWithIdentifiantSet(trc.suivi.core.repository.PliRepositoryTest): Unable to find trc.suivi.core.domain.Utilisateur with id 1; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find trc.suivi.core.domain.Utilisateur with id 1
```

for the following test:

```
@Test
public void testFindPlisByMultiFieldWithIdentifiantSet() {
    PliDataOnDemand dod = new PliDataOnDemand();
    Pli pli = dod.getSpecificPli(0);
    pli.setIdentifiant("theIdentifiant");
    pliRepository.save(pli);
    PliQueryInfo pliQueryInfo = new PliQueryInfo();
    pliQueryInfo.setIdentifiant("theIdentifiant");
    List<Pli> plis = pliRepository.findPlisByMultiField(pliQueryInfo, null, null, "identifiant", "desc");
    assertEquals(1, plis.size());
}
```

Comment: Could you post the Maven versions and the arguments that you used when running it within Eclipse and elsewhere? =)

Answer (score 5):

This is how to expose dependency jars to maven and aspectj weaver:

```
<project>
  ...
  <dependencies>
    ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
      <version>1.7.3</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
      <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <weaveDependencies>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.agroup</groupId>
              <artifactId>to-weave</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
            <weaveDependency>
              <groupId>org.anothergroup</groupId>
              <artifactId>gen</artifactId>
            </weaveDependency>
          </weaveDependencies>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  <build>
  ...
</project>
```

Source: [aspectj-maven-plugin](http://mojohaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/examples/weaveJars.html)

Comment: This solution fixed my issue.  I linked here via: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16502470/why-do-i-get-a-not-exposed-to-the-weaver-warnings-when-making-my-spring-project

Answer (score 3):

Why you are calling `dod.init()` by yourself? You could autowire data on demand. And don't forget annotate your test class with `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)`.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml")
@Transactional
public class PliTest {

  @Autowired
  private PliDataOnDemand dod;

  // your tests
}
```

**Update**
Seeing your maven output I would say there is something wrong with `aspect` weaving. 
From your output `has intertyped method from` and `this affected type is not exposed to the weaver`.

**Update 2**
Read about `Managing multiple projects` from
http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Introducing-AJDT/article.html.
Try to configure `aspectj-maven-plugin` using `weaveDependencies` or `weaveDirectories` parameter
http://mojo.codehaus.org/aspectj-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html#weaveDependencies.

Comment: Hello Alzksandr. I am calling `dod.init()` because it is required if you don't call methods such as `dod.getSpecificPli(0)`. Otherwise, the domain model is not populated. I tried the solution you suggested: it does not work either.

Comment: Hmm... Have you changed something in your `pom.xml`? Especially inside `<build>`. Maybe some aspects are not getting weaved.

Comment: Hi! Good point. I hadn't thought about that. It seems the aspects are correctly weaved. See edit.

Comment: Try to persist something inside one of your test method and see if any exception comes up. Also I noticed that your test method not throwing exceptions so add `throws Exception` to it.

Comment: `Utilisateur` is one other Entity in my domain model.

Comment: Seems like your test depends on some other test. See if you can run ONLY this Pli test in Eclipse.

Comment: JUnit tests run from Eclipse pass successfully. One other thing to mention:  `Utilisateur` is the first entity to be populated by DOD and DOD fails there....

Comment: I had not seen your edit: sorry. Anyway, I am not sure how to interpret those aspectj warnings... I have added the `aspectJ` tag to my post.